# Dual screen (extended) is not working (Debian, Xfce)

Tags: debian, xfce, intel-graphics

I have following problem with a little outdated industrial PC. The PC has an Intel Atom processor D2550 with GMA3600 graphics.

I cannot use two screens (extended).

- Is it a GPU driver problem?
- Some setup problem (HDMI port is listed as DVI in xrandr)?

I have a fresh Debian buster with kernel 4.19.0-6-amd64 installed and everything works except for the second monitor - it is black and the monitor says no signal. The first is connected via DVI, the second via HDMI.

However Xfce (4.12.5) detects both monitors, I am able to set it.

[image: Xfce display settings]

I already did some research, but nothing works.

I tried to change everything in hardware, so it is not a hardware problem.

I can see the extra screen via VNC.

xrandr output:

```
xrandr --current
  Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2960 x 1050, maximum 4096 x 4096
  VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DVI-D-1 connected 1280x1024+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
    1280x1024     60.02*+
    1280x960      60.00
    ...
  DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DVI-D-2 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
    1680x1050     59.95*+  59.88  
    1600x1024     60.17  
    ...
  DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

lspci output:

```
lspci -s 0:02.00 -vv
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 31
    Region 0: Memory at dfc00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Region 1: I/O ports at f100 [size=8]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=07 <?>
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: fee01004  Data: 4022
    Kernel driver in use: gma500
    Kernel modules: gma500_gfx
```

Comment: Can you provide full output of xrandr (especially the line with "Screen") ?

Can you try this in a terminal :
xrandr --output DVI-D-1 --right-of DVI-D-2 --pos 1680x0 --mode 1280x1024

Comment: added xrandr output, tried the command, but monitor remains black

Comment: @Kajienk What does `xrandr` output with @Nathael command ? Any error ? Do you have anything on `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` related to this ?

Comment: output with @Nathael command is none, no error. Searching log file.

Comment: Ok, screen has taken your configuration into account (current 2960 x 1050) so I think the missing step is to tell XFCE to take new config into account. I'm using FVWM and with FVWM I have to "restart" fvwm for modifications on screens to take effect (this keeps all apps open, only with no window decorations for a second or two, and everything come back with new config taken into account. I think that there's something equivalent in XFCE.

Comment: Acording to Wikipedia, when using GMA3000 series you need to have chipset Q965 for independent display support, otherwise it's just a mirrored display. So it might be a hardware limitation. You could just install any modern cheap dedicated graphics adapter, for your desired dual display support. I recommend using AMD graphics card, as they have better driver support than nVIDIA. For example you may use an AMD RX 550 -> https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-550

Comment: PS sorry, I did not see than someone has pulled out this old thread from the graveyard... -.- really, this should not happening. I would be glad if old threads would be closed forever, if someone want's to add something, he should open a new thread...